# What makes Monocrystalline silicon a good semi-conductor?

Tags: semiconductor-physics, structure-formation

I'm researching Monocrystalline silicon for a school project and focusing on its application in Electronics.

One area I'm researching is why the material is a good semiconductor, and what properties of it make it good for use in Electronics.

Any information (with sources if not too much trouble) would be greatly appreciated!